# GA, merging results for many subpaths

Tags: google-analytics, localization

Recently I got access to Google Analytics account for a certain web application. This web application is multilingual, and language is specified as the first part of the URL path component, ie.:

```
/eng/items/show/14/
/spa/items/show/14/
/fre/items/show/14/
…
/eng/users/list/
/spa/users/list/
/fre/users/list/
…
```

Each page displays the same items (so, the same exact content), except using an interface localized in a specific language. However, Google Analytics user interface shows these pages as different pages.

Is it possible to make Google Analytics merge the counts for such pages?

I know I can export some data into CSV/Excel and do the merging myself, but then I lose the GA interface, which is a pretty nice thing to have.